# Text OverFlow with Comment Box

Tags: html, css, comments, overflow

I am pulling PHP into a form and have put some dummy data in for the actual message so I can mess with lengths.

The answer I need is with CSS as I tend to have bad practice and could really do with some help improving.

So the comment has an image, sender name, date posted, and message. I will show an image of it below.

The only problem I have is that text in my paragraph of tags of a very long length wraps within the `div`, but the text goes below the comment (also shown below).

Could I have some tips please on how to effectively make the comment box size grow with the text.

Here is my code:

```html
% for comment in comments %}
<div id="comment-list">
   <div class="individual-comments">
       <div class="comment-user">
          Sent by: {{comment.senderName}} <br>
          <img src="{{ asset('img/no-user.png') }}" width="50px" height= "50px" alt="User Image">
       </div>                
       <div class="comment-desc">
          <p>Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages</p>
       </div>                 
       <div class="comment-time">
          On: {{comment.dateCreated|date("m/d/Y")}}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

```css
.individual-comments {
  width: 700px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 0.5px solid #000000;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

.comment-desc {
  width: 613px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  padding-top: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.comment-time {
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}

.comment-user {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use height:auto; for the container.

Comment: That has not worked. The box's have gone with loads of text just mashed together.

Comment: I also tried min-height: 80px;
    height: auto; but then it is like it was before.

Comment: Sir can you please make a fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7d8dysdg/

Comment: Check this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d8dysdg/1/), use `flexbox` instead of positioning

Comment: Very good. I will read up on flex box now. One question, how do I adjust the text position. For example I want it just slightly left of where it is. (more near the image), how can I achieve this with flex?

Comment: The problem is, is that a longer name pushes the text over to the right.

Comment: You could put the user name text outside the comment-user box and give him an absolute positionning like the .comment-time, but with a left: 10px. The .comment-user would then only take space up to the image's width and the comment text would then be closer to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using positionning the wrong way.

Your `.comment-user` class is `relative` and so is your `.comment-time`, but your `.comment-desc` is `absolute` which leads to confusion.

> Also you should avoid fixed styles values when working with dynamic
>   elements.

Your fixed height on `.individual-comments` forces the div to never resize. It's the same with the `.comment-desc`.

Below is an example of a better layout, using `display: flex` for the container.
Another solution would have been to use `float: left` for `.comment-user`, `.comment-desc` and `.comment-time` and % widths (something like 20%, 70%, 10%). But again, working with dynamic data is better suited with adaptative layouts (so is flex!).

All comments are useless code I left for demonstration.

```css
.individual-comments{
    width: 700px;
    /* height: 80px; useless */
    border: 0.5px solid #000000;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.comment-desc{
    /* width: 613px;
    height: 50px; */
    position: relative;
    /* bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; */
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
    flex: 1;
}

.comment-time{
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    /* margin-right: 10px; */
    color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}

.comment-user{
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="comment-list">
   <div class="individual-comments">
       <div class="comment-user">
          Sent by: testuser <br>
          <img src="" width="50px" height= "50px" alt="User Image">
       </div>                
       <div class="comment-desc">
          <p>Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messagesText messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages</p>
       </div>                 
       <div class="comment-time">
          On: date
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT :

I used a position: absolute on .comment-time to allow the comment text to take all the right space. If I used a relative positionning, the .comment-desc would have been truncated by the .comment-time's width.